# Image could not be accessed on a registry to record

Tags: docker, hadoop, dockerfile, docker-swarm

I am trying to create a hadoop master service but I get this error

`image hamza/hadoop:2.7.4 could not be accessed on a registry to record
its digest. Each node will access hamza/hadoop:2.7.4 independently,
possibly leading to different nodes running different
versions of the image`

the service I'm trying to create

```
docker service create \
    --with-registry-auth \
    --name hadoop-master \
    --network swarm-net \
    --hostname hadoop-master \
    --constraint node.role==manager \
    --replicas 1 \
    --detach=true \
    --endpoint-mode dnsrr \
    --mount type=bind,source=/etc/localtime,target=/etc/localtime,readonly \
    --mount type=bind,source=/data/hadoop/config,target=/config/hadoop \
    --mount type=bind,source=/data/hadoop/hdfs/master,target=/tmp/hadoop-root \
    --mount type=bind,source=/data/hadoop/logs/master,target=/usr/local/hadoop/logs \
    hamza/hadoop:2.7.4
```

any help please  ?